# Do you place endnotes (in vancouver reference style) after colons or before?

Tags: citations

I have some references I would like to tie to all the dot points I've written after my colon and hence I thought it would be a good idea to put the relevant references after the colon, in endnote form. Here is an extract from the text I am putting together that illustrates what I mean:

```
These acute attacks are typically triggered in genetically susceptible individuals by at least one of the following:2-4
•   Stress
•   Medications (especially sulfa-containing antibiotics, barbiturates, synthetic oestrogens, certain antiepileptic drugs and a few others. See http://www.drugs-porphyria.org/ for details regarding safe and unsafe drugs)
•   Dietary changes (high protein diets, low-carbohydrate diets and fasts are especially notable for causing acute attacks)
•   Endocrine factors (fluctuations in the levels of the different hormones present in the body; usually the sex hormones such as oestrogens and androgens [e.g. testosterone, dihydrotestosterone]. Acute attacks are often triggered by the hormonal changes that occur in the different stages of development, e.g. puberty, menopause, etc.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively minor point, but in standard American English usage, footnote and endnote numbers would go *after* a punctuation mark, not before one. Usage in British English might be different, and individual publishers may have their own guidelines.

However, one might also ask why you aren't citing each item in the list separately; it might be more informative to the user rather than doing an all-purpose citation at the top of the list!

Comment: Depends on the reader. This guide I'm writing is for the laymen and since the purpose of all this referencing is rather to give them things to refer to and to give the writing some authority I didn't deem that necessary.